# Clojure record: how to get hinted type given an attribute name

Tags: clojure, record

I'm wondering is there a way to retrieve the type hinting associated with attributes declared with defrecord. e.g., if I have the following record definition:

```
(defrecord Foo [^Integer id ^String description])
```

I'd like to retrieve a map on `Foo` type that gives me the attributes and their hinted types. I know I can get a list of declared attributes through reflection:

```
(->> record .getDeclaredFields (remove #(java.lang.reflect.Modifier/isStatic (.getModifiers #))))
```

This does give me a list of declared fields, but their types are `Object`. I know Clojure is a dynamic language, but it'd be nice if the types are given back to me when I need them.

Comment: in future versions of Clojure, it's possible / quite likely that you will get the actual types back when you do this... i.e. don't count on the internal implementation staying the same!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but `(let [i 42 desc "Forty two" record (Foo. i desc)] [(type (:id record)) (type (:description record))])` => `[java.lang.Integer java.lang.String]`.  Probably no what you want, though, because: `(let [i "Not and int" desc 999 record (Foo. i desc)] [(type (:id record)) (type (:description record))])` => `[java.lang.String java.lang.Integer]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type hints are not kept anywhere. You can manage this information userself by writing a wrapper macro for defrecord which keeps the type information. You could e.g. generate a build function for the record type that enriches the instance with metadata on the fields:

```
(defrecord-hinted Foo [^Integer id ^String description])

; you could then acces the type information with
(->> (meta (make-Foo 42 "forty two")) 
     ::field-types
     :id) ; => java.lang.Integer.class
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344872/type-hinting-not-enforced-in-defrecord-constructors). It seems that type hints on fields are not used for much of anything currently, as opposed to hints on function arguments and return values.