# clojure sequence type

Tags: clojure, static-typing, typechecking

What's the correct type of a sequence? I have this code:

```
(defrecord MethodInfo [^clojure.lang.ISeq preconds ^clojure.lang.ISeq postconds])
```

But it doesn't seem to correctly enforce the type requirements, since I can write `(new MethodInfo 1 2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that Clojure's **[Type Hints](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Type%20Hints)** are only there for performance reasons, to improve method lookup by side-stepping reflection; That is their only purpose, and not to enforce static types in a dynamic language.

Please see [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344872/type-hinting-not-enforced-in-defrecord-constructors/3346656#3346656).

**Edit:**

There is talk of being able to [enforce primitive return types in some cases in Clojure 1.3](http://osdir.com/ml/clojure/2011-05/msg00349.html), but this is clearly something that's in flux, and still wouldn't apply to sequence types.

Comment: Mostly true. You can typehint in a definterface, and the interface generated will have fields of the right type. That's strictly for interop purposes, though, and you're right about not enforcing static types in general.